# Which methods are being covered by a pointcut?

Tags: java, aspectj, pointcut

Is it possible to know which methods are covered with a pointcut in AspectJ?

The background for this question is that I have a pointcut which covers every method (except for its own):

```
pointcut traceMethods() : (execution(* *(..))&& !cflow(within(MethodTrace)));
```

I would like be able to created a list of method-signatures for every method covered by the pointcut *once the application has started.* Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

For what you want the following would:

```
pointcut traceMethods() : (execution(* *(..))&& !cflow(within(MethodTrace)));

before() : traceMethods()
{
     // Holds the signature the method intercepted by the pointcut traceMethods()
     String s = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().toString();  

     // do something with string 's'
}
```

More information about it [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/language-thisJoinPoint.html):

> AspectJ provides a special reference variable, thisJoinPoint, that
> contains reflective information about the current join point for the
> advice to use. The thisJoinPoint variable can only be used in the
> context of advice, just like this can only be used in the context of
> non-static methods and variable initializers. In advice, thisJoinPoint
> is an object of type org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint